# Kubernetes ingress nginx not working for HTTP but works on HTTPS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am using the [kubernestes ingress ngix](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start) controller. When I go to `example.com` it shows ***(HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found)*** when it is on HTTP, but when I set the URL to HTTPS as `https://example.com` it works. Below is the Ingress service `inress-srv.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata: 
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /create-posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: query-srv
                port:
                  number: 4002
          - path: /posts/?(.*)/comments
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: comments-srv
                port:
                  number: 4001
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

When running `kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx`  gives:

| Name | Type | Cluster-IP | External-IP | Port(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ingress-nginx-controller | LoadBalancer | xx.xxx.x.53 | localhost | 80:31797/TCP,443:37888/TCP |
| ingress-nginx-controller-admission | ClusterIP | xx.xxx.x.16 | <none> | 443/TCP |

I tried restarting/resetting Docker and Kubernetes as well as `kubectl rollout restart deployment <depl-name>` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"`. I have set `127.0.0.1 example.com` in

> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Modifying the `/etc/hosts` like that seems unnecessary and probably broken. Is `posts.com` an example domain?

Comment: It's worth checking your Nginx logs to see what's going on internally.

Comment: @tadman yes its just localhost example domain. When checking logs i see few things like the log says: "Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work. Creating API client host="https://xx.xx.x.1:443", why not on port 80 for HTTP? Also it logs multiple times "Service "default/client-srv" does not have any active Endpoint. Service "default/comments-srv" does not have any active Endpoint."

Comment: In the Nginx ingress specifically, not Kubernetes as a whole. If you drop into the `nginx-controller` pod you can find `/var/log/nginx` with all kinds of details in the logs.

Comment: It's odd you're having the opposite of the usual problem, HTTPS fails, but HTTP works due to certificate issues, etc.

Comment: yeah, weird issue!.. in nginx I see `access.log -> dev/stdout` and `error.log -> /dev/stderr` but when saving stderr/stdout it says ` Could not find the file /dev/stderr` or `stdout`.  looks like I need to uninstall everything and then try again

Comment: It could be a broken container build, but that seems unlikely, the ingress is usually tested quite well. A missing `stderr` is exceptionally strange, though.

Comment: fixed my issue it was not at all related to kubernetes or ingress. Previously, I defined `example.com` in my `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file as `127.0.0.1 example.com`, which I changed to `127.0.0.1 example.com ::1 example.com`. Now its working on HTTP. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'd avoid doing that in the future, hence my "probably broken" comment.